# Fn key working nondeterministically

Tags: 14.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys, toshiba-satellite

I'm having a problem with my Toshiba Satellite running Ubuntu 14.04.  The <kbd>Fn</kbd> key is working nondeterministically, causing unintended consequences for my computer.  As an example, as we all know, <kbd>F5</kbd> is the browser refresh key.  However, <kbd>F5</kbd> is also the key that causes the display to change between the main display and an external monitor.  Sometimes when I press <kbd>F5</kbd> with a browser open, the page will refresh and when I press <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> the display will change, and sometimes the opposite happens, seemingly at random (although it changes only when the computer reboots; the behaviour is constant as long as the computer is not rebooted).

To answer the obvious question: The <kbd>Fn</kbd> key is not sticky as best as I can tell.

Comment: Is there a "fn lock" type of function on your keyboard?

Comment: No, there isn't.  Not as far as I can see anyway.  I'm using a different setup now which doesn't use an external monitor though, so I haven't tested in a while.

Answer (score 1):

**It's really hard to tell if a key is sticking but they often do.**

With a standard PC keyboard (inexpensive), I've often turned them upside down and rapped on the bottom and been amazed at the crud that fell out.

With a laptop keyboard that is more expensive and harder to replace sometimes I'll just tap the key repeatedly until it works as advertised.

Blowing the keys out with canned air often works and if your not big on replacing things is likely the best idea.

***I've never seen a software problem that was intermittent that didn't have an underlying hardware problem*** (bad sector in swap, stuck bit in RAM, short in cable, crud in keyboard, cold solder joint...)

Comment: The laptop was in brand new condition when the issue began.  There's nothing underneath the keyboard.

Comment: @Ertai87 expanded answer to cover manufacturing defect. Also the idea was that there might be something under the actual key, not the keyboard. I apologize if that wasn't clear.